# numbers from egrep result in one line

Tags: grep

I use egrep to output some lines with platform names:

```
XXX | egrep "i686-nptl-linux-gnu$|i686-w64-mingw32$|x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu$|x86_64-w64-mingw32$"

[30]    i686-nptl-linux-gnu
[34]    i686-w64-mingw32
[75]    x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
[77]    x86_64-w64-mingw32
```

what I need is:

```
export PLATNUMS=30,34,75,77
```

How can I pipe the egrep command to sed / awk / bash script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$ command | awk -F'[][ \t]+' '/i686-nptl-linux-gnu$|i686-w64-mingw32$|x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu$|x86_64-w64-mingw32$/{printf "%s%s",(f?",":"export PLATNUMS="),$2; f=1} END{print""}'
export PLATNUMS=30,34,75,77
```

How it works

- `-F'[][ \t]+'`

  Use any number of spaces, tabs, or `[` or `]` as field separators.
- `/i686-nptl-linux-gnu$|i686-w64-mingw32$|x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu$|x86_64-w64-mingw32$/`{...}`

  For the lines of interest, perform the commands in curly braces.
- `printf "%s%s",(f?",":"export PLATNUMS="),$2; f=1`

  For the lines of interest, print what we want.

  The variable `f` marks whether this is the first line of interest.
- `END{print""}`

  After reading all lines, print a newline.

#### Creating a shell variable

```
export PLATNUMS=$(command | awk -F'[][ \t]+' '/i686-nptl-linux-gnu$|i686-w64-mingw32$|x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu$|x86_64-w64-mingw32$/{printf "%s%s",(f?",":""),$2; f=1} END{print""}')
```

For example, if the file input contains your data:

```
$ export PLATNUMS=$(awk -F'[][ \t]+' '/i686-nptl-linux-gnu$|i686-w64-mingw32$|x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu$|x86_64-w64-mingw32$/{printf "%s%s",(f?",":""),$2; f=1} END{print""}' input)
$ declare -p PLATNUMS
declare -x PLATNUMS="30,34,75,77"
```

For those who prefer their commands spread out over multiple lines:

```
export PLATNUMS=$(command | awk -F'[][ \t]+' '
    /i686-nptl-linux-gnu$|i686-w64-mingw32$|x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu$|x86_64-w64-mingw32$/{
        printf "%s%s",(f?",":""),$2
        f=1
    }

    END{
        print""
    }
    ')
```

Comment: this ptrints the result but it's not a real export - I made this: `export PLATNUMS=$(XXX | awk -F'[][ \t]+' '/i686-nptl-linux-gnu$|i686-w64-mingw32$|x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu$|x86_64-w64-mingw32$/{printf "%s%s",(f?",":""),$2; f=1}')`

Comment: @bais Thanks for clearing that up.  Your code looks very good!  I just added to the answer the code to do create and export the shell variable.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this way, I can't try with your egrep.

```
export PLATNUMS=$(XXX | egrep "i686-nptl-linux-gnu$|i686-w64-mingw32$|x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu$|x86_64-w64-mingw32$" | sed ':A;s/\[\([[0-9]*\)].*/\1/;$bB;N;bA;:B;s/\n/,/g')
echo $PLATNUMS
```

How this work ?

Your egrep command return a multiline text
so sed read this text line by line this way

```
sed '
:A                      # label A

# here with your example
# on the first line the pattern space look like that
# [30]    i686-nptl-linux-gnu

# on the second line the pattern space look like
# 30
# [34]    i686-w64-mingw32

s/\[\([[0-9]*\)].*/\1/  # substitute all digit enclose by [] by only the digit

# on the first line the pattern space become
# 30

# on the second line the pattern space become
# 30
# 34

# and so on for each line

$bB                     # on the last line jump to B
N                       # get a newline in the pattern space
bA                      # It is not the last line so jump to A
:B                      # label B

# here we have read all the line
# the pattern space look like that without the #
# 30
# 34
# 75
# 77

s/\n/,/g'               # subtitute all \n by a comma

# the pattern space become
# 30,34,75,77

# $(XXX | egrep .... | sed ...) return 30,34,75,77 in the variable PLATNUMS

# It is better not to use all capital letters in your variable name
```

Comment: works too - not readable for me, but it's very compact - great!

Answer (score 0):

With `GNU sed` and `tr`:

```
$ XXX | egrep "i686-nptl-linux-gnu$|i686-w64-mingw32$|x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu$|x86_64-w64-mingw32$" | sed -E 's,]\s+.+$,,g'  | sed 's,^\[,,g' | tr '\n' ',' | sed -E 's,(^.+$),export PLATNUMS=\1,' | sed 's/,$//' && echo
```

I'm not sure what you want to achieve but you might want to automatically `eval` the output `export`:

```
$ eval $(XXX | egrep "i686-nptl-linux-gnu$|i686-w64-mingw32$|x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu$|x86_64-w64-mingw32$" | sed -E 's,]\s+.+$,,g'  | sed 's,^\[,,g' | tr '\n' ',' | sed -E 's,(^.+$),export PLATNUMS=\1,' | sed 's/,$//' && echo)
$ echo $PLATNUMS                                                                                                                                                                                  
30,34,75,77
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ever think you need grep+sed or 2 greps or 2 seds or any other combination then you should use 1 call to awk instead, and you never need grep or sed when you're using awk:

```
export PLATNUMS=$(XXX | awk -F'[][]' '/(i686-nptl-linux-gnu|i686-w64-mingw32|x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu|x86_64-w64-mingw32)$/{p=(p ? p "," : "") $2} END{print p}')
```

Btw in case it's useful, here's a couple of briefer regexps:

```
(i686-(nptl-linux-gnu|w64-mingw32)|x86_64-(unknown-linux-gnu|w64-mingw32))$
((i686-nptl|x86_64-unknown)-linux-gnu|(i686|x86_64)-w64-mingw32)$
```

and depending on your input data (since this will include combinations not provided by the above) you MIGHT only need:

```
(i686|x86_64)-(nptl|unknown|w64)-(linux-gnu|mingw32)$
```